# Filtering and summing sublists with Cases

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I've declared a list:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2}, {3, 4, 1}, {5, 4}, {3, 3}, {a, b, c}, {e, 
    f}, {g}, {}, {Sin[a], Cos[b]}};
```

now I've made an rule which add 2 pairs together:

```
Cases[list, {x_, y_} -> x + y]
```

later only Integer numbers:

```
Cases[list, {x_Integer, y_Integer} -> x + y]
```

But now i want find the sum of sublists which have the `Length >=2`  so that the result is:

> ```
> {3,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}
> ```

and after that I want to find the sum of all sublists so that the result would be:

> ```
> {3,2,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,g,0,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}
> ```

Thanks for helping

Comment: `Cases[list, {x_Integer, y_Integer} -> x + y]`

Comment: the length shouldn't be lower than >=3

Comment: `list /. {x_Integer, y_Integer} -> {x + y}` returns `{{8}, {2}, {2, 6, 7}, {5}, {2.5, 3.2}}`. However, I am not sure that this is what you want. You really should include your desired result in the question.

Comment: Yes that is the result what i want. But now i want to do this Cases[list, {x_Integer, y_Integer} -> x + y,Length>=3] so that only the lists which are higher and equal 3 as a sum in a result

Comment: `Cases[list, {x_Integer, y_Integer} /; x + y >= 3 :> x + y]`?

Comment: @Katze, the one you show is not the correct syntax for `Cases`; furthermore, I am not convinced that `Cases` is really what you want. You probably want [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) instead. Please edit your question to specify exactly what your desired result should be.

Comment: Is something like this what you want? `list /. {x_Integer, y_Integer} /; x + y >= 3 :> {x + y}` which returns `{{8}, {2}, {2, 6, 7}, {5}, {2.5, 3.2}}`.

Comment: @MarcoB this is my list list = {{1, 2}, {2}, {3, 4, 1}, {5, 4}, {3, 3}, {a, b, c}, {e, 
    f}, {g}, {}, {Sin[a], Cos[b]}}; I want the Sum of all Partlists which have the Length >= 2  and last i want the sum of all Partlist without condition. THanks

Comment: @Katze, As I said, please include EXPLICITLY what the result should be, i.e. show the list you want as output.

Comment: @MarcoB for the condition with >= should the result be {3,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}   and for the sum of all Partlists without any condition should be the result {3,2,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,g,0,Cos[b]+Sin[a]} I hope that i could explain now what i want, sorry for the communications-problems

Comment: @Katze OK that's a good starting point. Please include the contents of your latest comment in the question. You can use the "edit" button on the left, under the question.

Comment: @TomD thanks for your feedback. I've edit to the main question at the top the whole exercise. Please look there for the whole Question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Katze.  Maybe I am being stupid, but do the methods I posted not give the expected answers, ie `Cases[list, {x_, y__} :> x + y]` and `Total /@ list`?

Comment: @TomD yes you're right!!! Thank you. it works! why did the first "want1" works ? i could not understand it

Comment: @TomD i have a new list list = {{1, 2, 4}, 6, 7, 8, {8, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 1}};   i want to do it with an1) predicate Funktion in combination with Select        2) with Patter in combination with Cases to filter the Partlists which are have the sum 7. the solution is {{1,2,4},7,{3,4},{1,2,3,1}}

Comment: @Katze.  Maybe `Select[newlist, Total[{Sequence @@ #}] == 7 &]` where `newlist = {{1, 2, 4}, 6, 7, 8, {8, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 1}};`. Output is `{{1, 2, 4}, 7, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 1}}`.  Stephen Wolfram's book, [An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/preface.html), which you are probably aware of, explains things much better than I can.

Comment: Thats right!! Thanks TomD

Comment: @TomD but you don't use Cases...

Comment: @Katze.  I cannot see how `Cases` will be of use in your last example, but perhaps I am missing something. You possibly need to edit your question to include the new problem. For `Select`, you might prefer the syntax `Select[Total[{Sequence @@ #}] == 7 &][newlist]`. Note that `Pick` will also work. For example: `Pick[#, Total[{Sequence @@ #}] == 7] & /@ newlist`

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Total` and `Select`.

```
Total /@ Select[Length@# >= 2 &]@list
```

> {3, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}

```
Total /@ list
```

> {3, 2, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, g, 0, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of mapping: `Total[Select[list, Length[#] >= 2 &], {2}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Nice addition. +1

Answer (score 2):

Since you insist on using `Cases`:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2}, {3, 4, 1}, {5, 4}, {3, 3}, {a, b, c}, 
   {e,f}, {g}, {}, {Sin[a], Cos[b]}};

Cases[list, sub : {_, __} :> Total@sub]
```

> ```
>  {3, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}
> ```

Comment: Or, as I said in a comment, `Cases[list, {x_, y__} :> x + y]`

Comment: @TomD Sorry, missed that comment, just read first two and last two of them :/